# Block Codes Definition

Tags: information-theory

I'm studying Information Theory, specifically noisy channel coding, and I couldn't understand the definition of the (N, K) block codes.

Definition is as follows:

> **An (N, K) block code** for a channel Q is a list of, S=$2^{k}$,
>   codewords
>
> {$x^{(1)}$,$x^{(2)}$,..., $x^{(2^{(K)})}$}, $x^{(s)} \epsilon
> > A_{X}^{N}$, each of length N.  The number of codewords is integer but
>   the number of bits specified by choosing a codeword, $K\equiv
> > log_{2}S$, is not necessarily an integer.

And rate is defined as

> R=K/N

There is **S** number of codewords and each is the length of **N**. What does **K** mean here? What does **K** represent in the code?

Why is rate defined by **K** ? In my thinking rate of block code in a noisy channel should be number of bits carry information divided by length of the block. In that case if **K** is the number of bits carry information (non-redundant) what has **K** to do with the number of blocks, S=$2^{k}$?

Also in Wikipedia-block codes, **K** (referred as n in the wiki) is defined as the number of symbols in all block. That makes sense for me but don't hold with the definition of the book. Number of blocks is **S** in the definition and S=$2^{k}$ !

I couldn't answer this questions and really confused.

Comment: $K$ is the amount of entropy/information per codeword (under certain assumptions). It means the minimum average amount of information you need to be able to represent all the combinations. If there are 16 codewords then you can use 4 bits of information to uniquely refer to any one of them (identify each codeword with a four bit binary number from 0000 to 1111. If there are 32 codewords you need 5 bits. If there are say 20 codewords then you would need 5 bits for one codeword but if there were lots of codewords, you could devise a scheme (e.g. a kind of arithmetic coding) to use $\log_2K$ bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in Wikipedia-block codes, $K$ (referred as $n$ in the wiki) is defined as the number of symbols in all block. That makes sense for me but don't hold with the definition of the book. Number of blocks is $S$ in the definition and $S=2^k$ !

No. Don't confuse the "number of symbols in a block" (= block lenght= codeword length) with the "number of blocks" (= number of messages = number of codewords = codebook size).

In a $(n,k)$ *binary* block code,  $n$ is the block length (or number of bits in the codeword) and $k$ is the number of "information bits" or length of the "raw" (unencoded) binary message. Then, $S=2^k$ is the number of messages (or, equally, the number of codewords).

For example, a binary $(7,4)$ code has $S=2^4=16$ messages, which could be represented in raw binary encoding with 4 bits, and each of these messages is encoded in codeword (block) of length $7$. And the rate is $7/4$. The "number of symbols (here, bits) in a block" is 7 ($n$). The number of blocks (or messages) is 16.

The above definition generalizes this to codes that are possibly not binary, and where the number of messages is not necessarily a power of 2.